# Change IP address pool of docker bridge

Tags: docker

I wanted to set custom pool of IPs for docker containers' subnets. For this I followed this stopped docker daemon, deleted the `docker0` interface and recreated with custom NetworkId

```
systemctl stop docker
ip link del docker0
```

Used NetworkManager to recreate the `docker0` virtual bridge interface and turned it in on.

```
ant@ant ~> nmcli con up <UID>
ant@ant ~> ip addr
111: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3e:ff:1b:ce:e4:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/20 brd 172.20.15.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now when I start docker daemon back again,

```
ant@ant ~> systemctl start docker
ant@ant ~> ip addr
111: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3e:ff:1b:ce:e4:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The subnet I have set is `172.20.0.1/20` but as soon as I start the docker daemon, `docker0` interface's subnet is changed to `172.17.0.1/16`. I have some private IPs in the LAN that I wish to access, that lie in that subnet.

Is there a better way to configure the bridge interface?

Answer (score 9):

Jordan's answer creates a subnet work which is then specified while running an application on a container. This is helpful to restrict IP pool used while running a container.

However, it does not help to restrict the IP pool of the `docker0` virtual bridge interface created by the docker daemon. The answer I was looking for is as follows:

Docker runs a daemon that manages the containers. This daemon creates an interface `docker0` which is by default configured to use the `172.17.0.1/16` subnet for its operations. So, we need to configure the daemon to use the desired subnet.

`dockerd` is used to run the docker daemon. It has `--bip` bridge IP option (see [dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/)).

```
dockerd --bip=172.20.0.1/20
```

But most systems run docker using respective service managers to accomplish this. In such cases docker has a docker daemon configuration file at `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. [Docker linux daemon configuration](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#/linux-configuration-file)
So create daemon.json if it doesn't already exist and add `bip`.

```
{
    "bip":"172.30.0.1/20"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the subnet of docker0 bridge it remains same .
For the specific ip purpose use new network creation .
docker network create --subnet=172.20.0.1/20 foo
After run container in that network .
docker run -itd --net foo image_name
Suppose if you want to give specific ip for container. use
 docker run -itd --net foo --ip 172.20.0.12 image_name

Answer (score 0):

By creating a specific bridged container network you should be able to define ip addresses using this command. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#/a-bridge-network) is a good entrypoint.

```
$ docker network create --driver bridge --subnet 172.20.0.1/20 subnet
$ docker run --name app --network subnet <container>
```

all your containers should now have ip addresses in the chosen subnet.

In addition the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/build-bridges/) describes how you could create your own bridge connection.